# How to install or integrate typed.js with angular2/4?

Tags: angular, typed.js

I am trying to integrate typed.js into angular two but it's not working. The text appear alright but there is not animation. I have install jQuery and typed.js but the animation is still not working.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Typed } from 'typed.js';
import * as $ from 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  public ngOninit() {
    var options = {
    stringsElement: "#typed-strings",
    typeSpeed: 80,
    backDelay: 700,
    backSpeed: 100,
    showCursor: true,
    autoInsertCss: false,
    cursorChar: '|',
    loop: true,
    loopcount: Infinity,    
    shuffle: true,
    }

    var typed = new Typed("#typing", options);
  }
}
```

---

```
div id="typed-strings" >
<p>Typed.js is a <strong>JavaScript</strong> library.</p>
<p>It <em>types</em> out sentences.</p>
</div>
<span id="typing"></span>
```

---

.angular-cli.json 
import

```
"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/typed.js/lib/typed.min.js",
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
      ],
```

Comment: can you show us the import? either index.html or angular-cli.json

Comment: @Melchia please i have included the angular-cli.json import

Answer (score 3):

After install with `npm install typed.js`

```
  ngOnInit() {
    let options = {
      strings: ["Product ", "Web ", "UX/UI"],
      typeSpeed:200,
      backSpeed:10,
      showCursor: true,
      cursorChar: "",
      loop:true
    }

    let typed = new Typed(".typing-element", options);
  }
```

and in html you need to add this only this class

```
 <h1 class="typing-element"></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/typed.js/lib/typed.min.js"
      ],
```

Order is important when it comes to imports